# How to instantiate a calldata array?

Tags: solidity, arrays, calldata

I know how to instantiate a memory array. Looks like this:

```
address[] memory users = new address[](1);
users[0] = address(0x0);
```

But I cannot create a calldata array in this same fashion. Any pointers?

Comment: Calldata is used to reference the area with the message received by the contract. It is not possible to change its content or add more data. Why would you need to create more calldata?

Comment: I don't want to change its content. I need to call an internal function which takes in calldata, and as part of that I need to create a calldata array in a different on-chain function. I just want to instantiate a calldata array and never change it - in Solidity. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: You can only get them inside the external function that was called, e.g. `function foo(bytes calldata a) external { /* use a here */ }`. In some cases using `memory` instead of `calldata` will work. You can't create a `calldata` variable.

Comment: So there's no way to instantiate a calldata array from within Solidity? It has to be created from web3py or web3js?

Comment: You cannot "create" calldata but you can assign and pass around existing variables: `uint256[] calldata data = existing_data; some_function(data);`.

Comment: Say I have `uint foo = 1`. Can I assign a calldata uint[] array that contains this?

Comment: No, it is not possible to modify calldata, you can just pass references around. Why do you need an array with calldata? In most cases using memory should work.

Comment: Because I'm implementing an IFlashLoanReceiver interface for Aave, and that requires that the input data be calldata arrays. But I would like to also call that method from an internal function, and create calldata arrays to do so.

Comment: I've added a couple of workaround for that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy solution for inheriting from IFlashLoanReceiver is to create an internal function that is callable from the `executeOperation`.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: ISC

pragma solidity 0.6.12;

// Interface cannot be modified
interface IFlashLoadReceiver {
    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external returns (bool);
}

contract Demo is IFlashLoadReceiver {
    // Override inherited function
    function executeOperation(
        address[] calldata assets,
        uint256[] calldata amounts,
        uint256[] calldata premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) override external returns (bool) {
        // Call real implementation
        // Compiler takes care of calldata to memory convertion
        return doExecuteOperation(assets, amounts, premiums, initiator, params);
    }

    // Real implementation callable by other internal functions
    function doExecuteOperation(
        address[] memory assets,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256[] memory premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes memory params
    ) internal returns (bool) {
        // Do something with parameters
        return false;
    }

}
```

Another solution is to be aware that `calldata` and `memory` are not part of the function signature. So from the outside `function foo(bytes calldata x) external` has the same signature as `function foo(bytes memory x) public` so you can make the function public instead of external and replace `calldata` by `memory` where appropriate and it should work (tm).

```
contract Demo {
    function executeOperation(
        address[] memory assets,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        uint256[] memory premiums,
        address initiator,
        bytes memory params
    ) public returns (bool) {
        // do something
        return false;
    }
}
```